# Disable mouseenter when over element on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a way to disable **mouseenter** when the top-level navigation item is **clicked** & on **pageload** and re-enable again when the mouse leaves and enters the element again.

- User hovers over element = show submenu
- User clicks menu = hide submenu and only show submenu when user leaves menu elements and enters again.
- If user is over the element onLoad then only show submenu when user leaves element and enters again.

```js
$('.navmenu li').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
 $(e.target).next().addClass('js-hover')
}).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
 $(e.target).next().removeClass('js-hover')
});


$('.navmenu').on('click', function(e) {
 $(e.target).next().removeClass('js-hover')
  location.reload(true);
})
```

```css
.navmenu .submenu {
  display:none;
}

.navmenu li {
  display: inline;
}

.navmenu .submenu {
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  left:0
}

.navmenu li:hover .js-hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navmenu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu</a>
      <nav class="submenu">
        <ul>
          <li>Submenu 1</li>
          <li>Submenu 2</li>
          <li>Submenu 3</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
      <nav class="submenu">
        <ul>
          <li>Submenu 4</li>
          <li>Submenu 5</li>
          <li>Submenu 6</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you have example code that is executable, there's no need to post it to a 3rd party site and link to it (those links can die over time and future readers of your question won't get the benefit). Instead, when you are composing your question, just click the "code snippet" button on the toolbar and insert your code there (as I've done for you). Then it's all self-contained right here in your question.

Answer (score 0):

this could be done using variables and storing a state of element (if it should be hidden or not). But since you tried to do this through class attributes, I did the same. Here is simle example of one menu item, everything should be clear.

```
<nav class="navmenu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu</a>
      <nav class="submenu" hidden>
        <ul>
          <li>Submenu 1</li>
          <li>Submenu 2</li>
          <li>Submenu 3</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

and javascript:

```
$menuLink = $("nav.navmenu li > a");

$menuLink.click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("dontHide");
});

$menuLink.mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).next("nav.submenu").removeAttr("hidden");
  $(this).removeClass("dontHide");
});

$menuLink.mouseleave(function () {
    if(!$(this).hasClass("dontHide")) { 
    $(this).next("nav.submenu").attr("hidden", true);   
  }
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/g3fua461/24/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g3fua461/26/ - I've updated what i'm trying to do. Notice the flickering when mouse is over element onclick? I'm trying to disable mouseenter until mouse leaves element and re-enters.